# Symfony3 Deploying issue PDOException “could not find driver” in php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo

Hey everyone am trying to deploy my symfony 3 app i uploaded the project files set up my vps 1&1 hosting on `ubuntu 16.04` after i installed `php , mysql , apache2` .

i tried to run command
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:create`

## Error :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
An exception occured in driver: could not find driver

 [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
could not find driver

 [PDOException]
could not find driver
```

first i though it's maybe parameters problem but then i made some changes in my file `parameters.yml`like this code below :

```
This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
  database_host: 127.0.0.1
  database_port: 3306
  database_name: kuenstlerdienste
  database_user: Test
  database_password: xxxxx
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: null
  mailer_password: null
  secret: 40ea1d1efb058912e7ae152d2847c9834d97faa4
  authentication.handler.login_success_handler.class: KuenstlerdiensteBundle\Security\LoginSuccessHandler
```

i don't think this is typo cause credentials are valid and when i enter `mysql`
after login am getting this result

```
mysql> Show DATABASES
 -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| kuenstlerdienste   |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i also tested if pdo installed on my vps :  by typing `php -m` and it was mentioned in the result `PDO`

i don't get it if it's symofony issue or in mysql config files there's somthing missing , thanks to any help

Comment: You sure PDO Mysql is installed? PDO does not necessarily mean the mysql drivers is installed.

Comment: Try to activate `mysqlnd` driver. Search for it in php.ini and uncomment its line. See: [MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqlnd.php) - Introduction and overview.

Comment: Do you see: `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` ? Else, if you're on a Debian try: `apt-get install php-mysql`. You don't just need PDO, and if you just install `php`, you just have PDO without pdo_mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this to check if you have the module installed or not.

```
php -m | grep pdo
```

Expected something like:

```
pdo_mysql
```